# php Ternary operator while coding together with string

Tags: php

There are my codes:

```
$finfo=new SplFileInfo("animal.php");
print "Directory:".$finfo->isDir()?"Yes":"No"."<br />";
print "Directory:".($finfo->isDir()?"Yes":"No")."<br />";
```

After printer, It shows:
YesDirectory:No

I am comfused about that.What is happening to

```
<<print "Directory:".$finfo->isDir()?"Yes":"No"."<br />";>>
```

Comment: It is not printing the `<br />` as the result of the first test returns just `"Yes"` and the `<br />` would only show if the result of the first test was `"No"."<br />"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Concatenation has a higher precedence than the ternary operator

```
print "Directory:".$finfo->isDir()?"Yes":"No"."<br />";
```

concatenates `"Directory:"` with `$finfo->isDir()`and then executes the ternary comparison against that concatenated value, and a non-empty string evaluates as true

whereas

```
print "Directory:".($finfo->isDir()?"Yes":"No")."<br />";
```

executes the ternary comparison first, and then concatenates the result of that with `"Directory:"`

Comment: It means that print "Directory:".$finfo->isDir()?"Yes":"No"."<br />"; is equal to print ("Directory:".$finfo->isDir())?("Yes"):("No"."<br />"); Thank you,I get it now.